# Symfony 3.4: unable to purge entity cache from console command

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I am trying to evict the second level cache for a particular entity from within a Symfony console command,  is this possible?

The problem I run into is that it seems the second level cache is not initialised when used from within a command.

The following code returns **true** if run from within my controller but **false** if run from within a command:

```
$entityManager->getCache()->containsEntity('Entity\SomeEntity');
```

Unsurprisingly calling the evict method has no effect from within a command, but works fine from the controller.

Comment: do you run a command with `--env=prod`?

Comment: Lemme guess … are you using APC(u) as caching backend?

Comment: @lxg you are right and my issue was unrelated to APC(u), I'm removing my comment.